# React JS: Expected a string but got: object

Tags: reactjs

I have an icon.js file as shown below to export the icons of your need:

```
import RotateLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/RotateLeft';

const iconTypes = {
  LEFT_ROTATION: <RotateLeftIcon />,
};

export const iconNames = {
  LEFT_ROTATION: 'LEFT_ROTATION',
};

export const getIcon = (iconName, props) => {
  const Component = iconTypes[iconName];
  return <Component style={{ ...props }} />;
};
```

and I call them like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function TestingIcons() {
    return getIcon(iconNames.LEFT_ROTATION, {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: '1rem',
      });
}
```

When I do the above, I get this error: `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit with the following:

```
const iconTypes = {
  LEFT_ROTATION: RotateLeftIcon,
};
```